# Word describing a word used to reference a noun previously mentioned

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose I was writing this sentence: "John ran, and he shouted very loudly".

"He" in that sentence was referring back to John. I am quite sure there is a word describing this referring to a noun previously mentioned. Could someone help me out please?

Comment: Incomplete answer - hence the comment. You have 2 independent clauses in the sentence, and the "he" itself is a *Subject Pronoun* - but not sure what to term the repetitive pronoun, or whether such a term exists.

Comment: @JoseK, the second independent clause's subject refers to the first independent clause's subject, so I was wondering if there is such a term.

Comment: Should I assume "pronoun" isn't the word you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [anaphoric reference](http://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/think/knowledge-wiki/anaphoric-reference), as opposed to cataphoric reference.

*<sup>Disclaimer: That link is not to my site, but I work with someone who works on it.</sup>*

Comment: Or just "anaphora"